# Vagrant in Pycharm With Error " Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed. Contection Failed"

Tags: pycharm

m using Pycharm 3.4.2 and Vagrant and i perform  configure Pycharm with Vagrant Box for debugging or testing on my vagrant box.

But , when i add "remote python interpreter" through option "vagrant" in Configuration Interface , Pycharm always alerts "Test SFTP Connection:  Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed. Connection failed" althought I vagrant up successfully.

I don't know why and how to solve this problem. I need any help from you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is a Java related issue. I experience the same behaviour after upgrading Java with the following traceback

```
    2014-11-06 13:37:59,442 [7056598]   INFO - sdk.transport.SshRemoteSession - New ssh session created: vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222 
2014-11-06 13:54:14,896 [8032052]   WARN - lugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkUtil -  
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkUtil.testConnection(RemoteSdkUtil.java:245)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteInterpreterManagerImpl.testConnection(PyRemoteInterpreterManagerImpl.java:179)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData$2.vagrant(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:298)
    at com.intellij.remote.RemoteConnectionCredentialsWrapper.switchType(RemoteConnectionCredentialsWrapper.java:152)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.produceRemoteSdkCredentials(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:283)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.getRemoteSdkCredentials(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:239)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.getRemoteSdkCredentials(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:226)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.getRemoteSdkCredentials(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:26)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.ui.CreateRemoteSdkForm$5.compute(CreateRemoteSdkForm.java:212)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.ui.CreateRemoteSdkForm$5.compute(CreateRemoteSdkForm.java:206)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.ui.CreateRemoteSdkForm$7.produce(CreateRemoteSdkForm.java:234)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.ui.RemoteBrowseActionListener.actionPerformed(RemoteBrowseActionListener.java:31)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:463)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1557)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1524)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteInterpreterManagerImpl.addRemoteSdk(PyRemoteInterpreterManagerImpl.java:347)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkDetailsStep.b(PythonSdkDetailsStep.java:149)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkDetailsStep.a(PythonSdkDetailsStep.java:127)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkDetailsStep.access$400(PythonSdkDetailsStep.java:48)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkDetailsStep$4.run(PythonSdkDetailsStep.java:226)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup$18.run(AbstractPopup.java:1248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.a(FocusManagerImpl.java:651)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$2600(FocusManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$7.run(FocusManagerImpl.java:485)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2053)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:476)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.dispose(AbstractPopup.java:1254)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.dispose(WizardPopup.java:153)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.dispose(ListPopupImpl.java:290)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.disposeAllParents(WizardPopup.java:256)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.a(ListPopupImpl.java:407)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.a(ListPopupImpl.java:367)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:325)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyMouseListener.mouseReleased(ListPopupImpl.java:455)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyList.processMouseEvent(ListPopupImpl.java:510)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:463)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1557)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1524)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.a(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:72)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowSettingsAction.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:926)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:236)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.a(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Log in via command line to Vagrant works as expected.

Try the following: Make sure you only have one alias *localhost* defined in *"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"*

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
```

Comment: That was my problem.  When I removed all the aliases in addition to localhost I had defined for 127.0.0.1 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think here is the fix for your problem: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23403071-Network-connectivity-issues-when-running-under-Java-1-7